# Erro ao imprimir HTML com BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, python-requests, beautifulsoup

Tenho um código simples que acessa um site de quiz e pega todas as **ul** que contêm a classe **square** e imprime na tela.

```
url = "http://quizdomilhao.com.br/category/g1"
question_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(question_page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('ul',class_="square"))
```

Mas quando rodo esse código ele retorna o html todo do site.
Alguém me ajuda como posso resolver isso com BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'}

url = "http://quizdomilhao.com.br/category/g1"

question_page = requests.get(url, headers = headers )
question_page.encoding = 'utf-8'

soup = bs(question_page.text, 'html.parser')

ul = soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'square'})

lis = [item.find_all('li') for item in ul]
lis = [item for sublista in lis for item in sublista]

aas = [item.find_all('a') for item in ul]
aas = [item for sublista in aas for item in sublista]

text_link = [[item.text, item2['href']] for item, item2 in zip(lis,aas)]
```

1. Importando as bibliotecas
2. Criando um header para o site aceitar a requisição
3. Fazendo a requisição utilizando o requests
4. Utilizando o bs para conseguirmos extrair as tags html
5. Buscando as ul com a classe square
6. Utilizando o retorna da consulta anterior para extrair somente o conteúdo das li
7. Buscando 'a' dentro de ul
8. Criando uma lista com o conteúdo

---

**Update** para acessar as páginas de respostas

```
for item in text_link:
    question, link = item
    print(question)
    print(link)
    answer_page = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    answer_page.encoding = 'utf-8'
    soup = bs(answer_page.text, 'html.parser')
    ul = soup.find('ul', {'class':'square'})
    li = ul.find_all('li')  
    answer = [item.find('strong').text for item in li if item.find('strong')]
    print(''.join(answer))
```

Comment: Olá @Imonferrari como faço para os caracteres aparecem com acentuação?

Comment: @JoaRoque, bom dia! Adicionei um update a questão: `question_page.encoding = 'utf-8'`. Abraço!

Comment: @Imonferrari, até aí tudo bem! Agora como faço para extrair os links contidas nos li? Sempre que tento da algum erro! Porque eu quero na verdade guardar as questões e respostas no banco de dados e para pegar a resposta  tenho que acessar a página da resposta e pegar a resposta correta

Comment: @JoaRoque, fiz outro update para resolver a questão dos links. Abraço!

Comment: @JoaRoque, não entendi. Caso as duvidas dessa pergunta tenham sido respondidas é melhor você criar uma nova pergunta com as novas dúvidas, dessa forma fica mais fácil entender o que você precisa. O que acha? Abraço!

Comment: @JoaRoque, fiz uma atualização no código pois a página de perguntas contém mais de uma class square. Abraço!!